# jquery mobile basic modal dialog intermittently reloads on close

Tags: dialog, jquery-mobile

I have a very basic jquery mobile modal dialog that INTERMITTENTLY reloads on clicking "close". This happens across all devices but not on desktop browsers. 
The close button always works, but the dialog will pop back up randomly.
Anyone esle experience this. I'd post this on the jquery mobile forum but new registration is broken right now.

Comment: Please edit your question with a link to your code, Example code, Code you have tried, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, it's code related but the code won't tell you the what the problem is. The close button on the dialog was directly over the dialog's open button. So when you pressed close, the button beneath it was also being activated to open the dialog again. I moved the position of the close button to not be on top of the open button and that solved it. However, the bigger issue is having touch events read through all layers.